# Adding custom projection for Nepal in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, nepal, equal-earth-projection

I have to process data from Nepal. Modified Mercator projection(MUTM) is what I need but I can only find Mercator projection.

[image]

I used the closest Mercator projection (WGS 84 /UTM zone 45 N) for my project but the surveyed points don't lie in the correct position. I saw answer to this question for earlier version of QGIS (it was mentioned it works for version below 3.1 or 3.4) which was as follows:

Steps to use in QGIS:

1. SRS.db: paste this file in

   C:\Program Files\QGIS 18\apps\qgis\resources
2. ESRI_EXTRA.wkt: paste this file in

   C:\Program Files\QGIS 18\share\gdal

Now you can project map in NEPAL MUTM 81,84 or 87 as per requirement.

The mentioned files were also provided but but I am using QGIS 3.22 and I couldn't find the gdal folder. I am very new to QGIS and Python.

[image]

Comment: You can add a [Custom Coordinate Reference System](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#id10) to QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EPSG:102306 for Nepal MUTM. (It uses Nepal Nagarkot system Everest modified 1937, best available so far except you want to use seven parameter transformation) But this defines Central Meridian as 84. To use 81 or 87 as CM, you can edit the esri_extra.wkt file and change Central Meridian to your required value, or use your own wkt.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a Custom Coordinate Reference System, named MUTM,  using the WKT definition for MUTM (it is given in ESRI_EXTRA.wkt file you refer to):

```
PROJCS["MUTM84",GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["unnamed",6377276.345,300.8017000000115],TOWGS84[296.2,731.5,273,0,0,0,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",81],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

[image]

From there you can use the MUTM CRS :

[image]

Comment: Hi Kasper, I have done the same thing as you suggested. It validates that it is as per WKT too but I encounter one error after pressing "OK"

Comment: Hi Kasper, I have done the same thing as you suggested. It validates that it is as per WKT too but I encounter one error after pressing "OK", it displays  The definition of " is not valid. I have copied the details of  the projection as it is but still why error of ". I am not being able to attach a photo of it here.

Comment: Hi Kasper , I have attached a picture of the error in question itself as I couldn't add it in comment

Comment: @usha: I cannot say, Using QGIS 3.28 and copy pasting the exact WKT from the above answer works immediately. The one thing I notice in your screeshot is that there seems to be a blank line above the actual "MUTM 84" item in the "Define" window with the green/red +/-. I don't have that, the newly created CRS fills the very first line, it looks like you have a custom CRS with no name and no definition above the one you want

Comment: Thank you very much, Kasper. It worked. It was as you suggested a blank CRS